Existence of fundamental domain
I am trying to prove the existence of a fundamental domain for the free and properly discontinuous action of the group of deck transformations $\Gamma = \mathrm{Deck}(X)$ of the universal cover $\pi : X \to Y$ of a connected manifold $Y$.
I am aware of Dirichlet domains but I was wondering whether I could do something simpler.
Here is my attempt. Consider the set
$$S = \{ U \subseteq X \text{ open} \mid \pi|_U : U \to Y \text{ is injective}\}.$$
Inclusion makes $S$ into a (nonempty) partially ordered set. It easy to show that every linearly ordered subset of $S$ has a maximal element. Thus, by Zorn's lemma, we conclude that $S$ contains a maximal element $\Delta$. This is our candidate.
It is straightforward to see that $\Delta \cap g \Delta = \emptyset$ if $g \neq id$.
Now, the only thing I need to show is that $p(\bar{\Delta}) = Y$, since this would imply that
$$X = \pi^{-1}(Y) = \pi^{-1}(\pi(\bar{\Delta})) = \bigcup_{g \in \Delta} g \bar{\Delta}.$$
In order to prove that, it would be sufficient to show that $\pi(\bar{\Delta})$ is closed in $Y$. Here I'm stuck. Do I need to use the fact that the action of deck transformations is by isometries? That would basically give the costruction of Dirichlet domains.
Any help is highly appreciated!

First of all, I do not understand why do you find the Dirichlet construction complicated. It is general and does what is needed. Your proposed construction does not work. Here is a simple example. Start with the infinite cyclic group $\Gamma$ acting on the upper half-plane $X$ (by isometries of the hyperbolic metric) with the generator of $\Gamma$ acting as the dilation $z\mapsto 2z$. Take
$$
\Delta=\{z\in X: -2<Re(z)<-1 \}\cup  \{z\in X: 1<Re(z)<2 \}. 
$$
You will check that $\Delta$ is a maximal open subset of $X$ satisfying $g\Delta\cap \Delta=\emptyset$ for all $g\in \Gamma \setminus \{1\}$. However, the $\Gamma$-orbit of $cl\Delta$ is not the entire $X$: What is missing is the imaginary axis.
There are more complicated examples of "fake" fundamental domains obtained via your construction (for cyclic group actions on the hyperbolic 3-space), where the $\Gamma$-orbit of $cl\Delta$ is the entire $X$ but the quotient map $q: X\to X/\Gamma$ descends to a continuous bijective map $$
cl\Delta/\sim \ \ \to X/\Gamma$$
which is not a homeomorphism. (Something highly undesirable for fundamental domains.)   Here $\sim$ is the equivalence relation on $cl\Delta$ defined via the action of $\Gamma$ on $X$.

The Dirichlet construction is not complicated. I was simply wondering whether one could do away with the metric in such construction. Thank you very much for your answer though!
